# Create long URLs

Tags: url

Hey how do you manually create long urls like, www.google.com/finance/how-to-save.html

I tried to create a folder called finance on my web host, and the put my how-to-save.html web page inside but that didnt work.

Comment: Unless you own `www.google.com`, it won't work. :)

Comment: Sorry, joking aside - What you're describing **is** the way to do it. Can you specify exactly how it didn't work? Also, have you placed your `finance` directory in the right place (document root, i.e. wherever the html pages for your "short" URL would normally go?)

Comment: Yup I put the "finance" folder in the root directory of my web server, then put my how-to-save.html inside that "finance" folder, but when i go to www.google.com/finance/how-to-save.html it gives me a 404 Not Found

Comment: If you put a file in your root folder, can you see that in the hypothetical www.google.com/test.html?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain a bit more.

On my local box i can make a folder in my server path, and id get to it via: localhost/path/to/folder

or http://address.com/path/to/folder

Some things to check,  are the permissions set up so others can view, and is it in your web path

Comment: Yup I put the "finance" folder in the root directory of my web server, then put my how-to-save.html inside that "finance" folder, but when i go to www.google.com/finance/how-to-save.html it gives me a 404 Not Found

Comment: try checking permissions.  If you don't have access to the box, then lookup the .htaccess file

Comment: Checked permission on everything - i put everything on 777